# How do I make the Settings bar always show me the settings instead of the title

Tags: settings

This is what I'm talking about

[image: screen1]

I want it to show me this

[image: screen2]

At all times. How do I go about doing that. I know I did it before, but I forgot how, and I have no idea how that bar is even called.

Also I would like it, that if I have 2 windows open(imagine full screen browser with non-full screen terminal), that the settings bar would show at the top corner of each app, not of the app that is in the foreground. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in the: `System settings --> Appearance --> Behavior` Select the option `in the window's title bar` under the `Shows the menus for a window`. I believe this is where you get that done...

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I missed that. Thought it's called something else I guess.